How to render same model multiple time in React Three Fiber
I want to render same butterfly model multiple times. But it only render last model. How to fix it
This is Butterfly model that use gltf to jsx to make


export function Model(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements["group"]) {
  const group = useRef<THREE.Group>(null);
  const mesh = useRef<THREE.Group>(null);
  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF(
    "/models/animated_butterfly/scene.gltf"
  ) as GLTFResult;
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
      <group name="Sketchfab_Scene" {...props}>
        <group name="Sketchfab_model" ref={mesh}>
          <group name="root">
            <group name="GLTF_SceneRootNode" rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
              <group name="Armature_55">
                <group name="GLTF_created_0">
                  <primitive object={nodes.GLTF_created_0_rootJoint} />
                  <skinnedMesh
                    name="Object_7"
                    geometry={nodes.Object_7.geometry}
                    material={materials.Wings}
                    skeleton={nodes.Object_7.skeleton}
                  />
                  <skinnedMesh
                    name="Object_9"
                    geometry={nodes.Object_9.geometry}
                    material={materials.Wings}
                    skeleton={nodes.Object_9.skeleton}
                  />
                  <skinnedMesh
                    name="Object_11"
                    geometry={nodes.Object_11.geometry}
                    material={materials["Material.001"]}
                    skeleton={nodes.Object_11.skeleton}
                  />
                  <group name="Plane_52" />
                  <group name="Plane001_53" />
                  <group name="Plane002_54" />
                </group>
              </group>
            </group>
          </group>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/models/animated_butterfly/scene.gltf");

I import Butterfly model and use multiple times to View. But I don't shown on the screen. How to clone it ?
This is result i want
<View className=" h-full w-full z-0" orbit>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Butterfly
            position={[2, 0, 1]}
            rotation={[Math.PI / 1.5, Math.PI, 0]}
          />
          <Butterfly
            position={[1, 2, 1]}
            rotation={[Math.PI / 1.5, Math.PI, 0]}
          />
          <Butterfly
            position={[-2, 0, 1]}
            rotation={[Math.PI / 1.5, Math.PI, 0]}
          />
        </Suspense>
      </View>

